# Pass data to template outside view in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I mean, i have the classic always-present side panel where i would like to display some model data (eg. year/months for existing posts publication date, tags and alike).

Since this side panel is always present i also would like to avoid putting the retrieving logic in every view i define since it is repetitive, error/bug prone, less mantainable, etc.

Is there a way in django to define such logic and bind/inject its result in every view i made?

Even better it would be to do this directly in the template to decouple it from the views at all, so if i got a different page that don't need the data (like a login/out page) django won't waste work/time to retrieve/manipulate something that won't be even displayed.

thanks in advance

Comment: have you heard about `context_processor`? it is what you need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A context processor available in `CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` will be available in every template powered by that settings file, to create one:

- create a file in your project, name it `context_processors.py` next to `settings.py`
- Inside, create a function, like a view with the parameter `request` and should return a dict

  ```
  def function_name(request):
      variable = 'Hello World'
      # all stuff that you want to make available
      return {'variable':variable}
  ```
- Go to `settings.py`, add the path of your `context_processors.py`

  ```
  TEMPLATES = [
  {
      'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
      'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),],
      'APP_DIRS': True,
      'OPTIONS': {
          'context_processors': [
              'django.template.context_processors.debug',
              'django.template.context_processors.request',
              'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
              'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
              'project_name.context_processors.function_name',
          ],
      },
  },
  ]
  ```
- Now it's avaible in all templates powered by the `sesttings.py` file

  ```
  <p>here is the {{ variable }}</p>
  ```

Comment: I second this approach. I use it in pretty much all of my projects.

Comment: That's perfect, now i have to dig deeper in the topic. Just in case: is it possible to enable context processors just for specific templates?
As i said in the questions, i may have some pages that don't need the data coming from the context processor.

Comment: ok, it works perfectly, but is possible to use context processors data in a parent template? or even in a partial included in parent template?
I made a simple test and it seems not possible, i actually can just in the extending template file.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options here. You can either design a mixing that you can include in your class declaration and in there extend `get_context_data` like this:

```
class SidebarMixin():

   def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
       context = super(SidebarMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
       context['sidebar'] = mycontext #insert here your stuff

class MyView(View, SidebarMixin):
   def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
       context = super(MyView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
       context['mycontext'] = mycontext #insert here your stuff
```

otherwise you can define a new template tag:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('sidebar.html', takes_context=True)
def sidebar(context):
    return {
        'sidebar': mysidebar_context,
    }
```

Comment: While i still prefer @Lemayzeur answer, this answer is also very useful in my opinion since it show different approach that someone may found better dependind on use case